# How can I pause and resume all terminals that are running?

Tags: linux, command-line

How can I pause and resume all command line commands on the terminal in Linux. Not ( Ctrl +s & Ctrl + q)

Comment: A terminal is (these days) a program that allows you to interact with a shell such as `bash`. It's not the shell itself. What do you want to do with the pause and resume? Would `screen` or `tmux` better handle your actual requirement?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (control character `susp`) that sends SIGTSTP to a foreground application, effectively putting it in the background, suspended. You can go back into the application by running `fg` (or `%x` where `x` is the job number as shown in `jobs`).

However, if you mean pause and resume terminal's you can use a program called `screen` or `tmux`.

Sorry If I could not understand your original question, english was a bit incomprehensible.

Comment: Thank you for replying
but I'm need the command To work Ctrl +Z

Comment: @abu please [edit your question to explain more clearly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/386200/edit) what you want to achieve.