# How work the Ctrl +Z by command line not by keyboard key?

Tags: linux

How work the <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> by command line not by keyboard key? (on Linux)

I'm need stop all terminal are running and resume it later.

Comment: You asked this before at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386200/ , and with this duplicate you have not actually made clear the things that people have asked to be made clear.

Comment: Not a true duplicate. This question is about Ctrl-Z, the other is about Ctrl-S, but the answer is actually the same.

Comment: No, the other one is _not_ about Ctrl+S.  At least that much is stated in the question.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> writes the control character `susp`, which sends the signal `SIGTSTP` (number 20 on Linux amd64, 24 on Solaris amd64, 18 on FreeBSD amd64... it's better to avoid referring to signals by number as that's not portable) to all the processes in the foreground process group of the terminal.

You can send a signal to stop a process from the command line by using the `kill`-command.

```
kill -s STOP <pid>
```

(where `<pid>` is the id of the process you want to suspend) or, if you want to address all processes of a program with a certain name (technically, all processes whose name match a given extended regular expression):

```
pkill -STOP xterm
```

(where `xterm` is an example name).

When you need to resume the processes, send signal `SIGCONT` in the same way.

Comment: It sends the SIGTSTP (20 on Linux on amd64 at least) signal, not SIGSTOP, and to the foreground process _group_ of the terminal device. SIGTSTP can be handled, not SIGSTOP.

Comment: but how to know the number of session the terminal is running

Comment: What is the meaning of `pid` ?

Comment: @abuali "PID" is short for "process ID". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier

Comment: @ Stéphane Chazelas   how konw `process ID` special in the the terminal opened

Comment: I'm is running the some terminal , I'm need the stopped all this terminal and resume it later by script

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to stop all the processes that have `/dev/pts/12` as their controlling terminal (including all the foreground and background jobs running in that terminal and the shell), you could do:

```
pkill -STOP -t pts/12
```

That would also suspend the session leader. In some cases, that one may be resumed automatically. For instance, GNU `screen` resumes the session leader as soon as it detects that it has been suspended.

If you wanted to send the SIGTSTP signal to the foreground process group of that terminal like `^Z` would you'd do:

```
kill -s TSTP -- "-$pgid"
```

Where `$pgid` is the process group ID of that  foreground process group. On Linux and BSDs at list, you can find out which it is by running `ps -o tpgid= -p "$pid"` where `$pid` is the id of any process that has that terminal as its controlling terminal. On most systems, any of those processes could also find it out using `tcgetpgrp()`.

In both cases, you resume those processes by sending the SIGCONT signal in place of SIGSTOP/SIGTSTP.

Answer (score 0):

Send the `STOP` signal to the process(es) that you would like to suspend.

You may later send the `CONT` signal to unsuspend a suspended process.

For example:

```
pkill -STOP terminal
```

This would suspend all `terminal` processes.

```
 pkill -CONT terminal
```

This would unsuspend all processes named `terminal`.

Comment: but how to know the number of session the terminal is running

Comment: @abuali I'm not sure what you mean. `pkill` will look up all processes matching the name that you supply and send the signal to all of those. If you want to limit to a particular user, add `-u username`.